# Java | Cannot Find Symbol | Returning An Object

Tags: java, object, return, symbols

I am having a problem returning the object book that i have created, any help would be very greatly appreciated. The program is asking for a book then an author and that is stored into an object(book). It is then to be saved into an array of books.

```
**import java.util.*;
public class BookShop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
        book[] books = new book[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++){
            books[i] = getBook(kybd);
        }

        printBookDetails(books);
    }

    private static book getBook(Scanner kybd) {
        System.out.print("What Is The Title Of The Next Book?:>   ");
        String title = kybd.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Who Is The Author Of The Next Book?:>   ");
        String author = kybd.nextLine();

        if(author == null){
            book definedBook = new book();
            definedBook.setTitle(title);
        }
        else{
            book definedBook = new book();
            definedBook.setTitle(title);
            definedBook.setAuthor(author);
        }

        return definedBook;

    }

    private static void printBookDetails(book[] books) {

    }
}**
```

Comment: where is the import for book? is it in the same package?

Comment: Move book definedBook = new book(); to outside of the if...else statement.

Comment: where are you having problems? are you getting an exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of defining book object in if/else, just define it outside of if like:

```
book definedBook = new book();

 if (..) {
     //setter   
 } else {
  //setter
    ...
 }
 return definedBook;
```

Comment: Thank-you very much! Thats sorted it for me!

Answer (score 1):

Move the declaration of `book` so that it has scope like

```
book definedBook = new book();
if (author == null){
    // book definedBook = new book();
    definedBook.setTitle(title);
} else{
    // book definedBook = new book();
    definedBook.setTitle(title);
    definedBook.setAuthor(author);
}
```